# How can I automate none-PATH plink (Putty Link) on windows? and get its output?

Tags: powershell, process, plink, redirectstandardoutput

I have been trying both standard PS1 using what I read about using:

```
ECHO y | plink .....
```

But the issue I have is that plink is being saved on a network drive.  I can call it using:

```
$plink = "P:\path\plink.exe"
echo y | &$plink -ssh -l user-pw password $addrss exit
&$plink -ssh -l user -pw password -m "P:\path\SCOTDiagScript.txt" $addrss
```

The issue I have is that if I run plink manually via cmd, I get output, that I need to read and possibly display to the user.  Piping the last line  to Out-File gives me nothing and if I try to call cmd to then redirect to a txt file, I get an error because the path for plink has a space in it; and I am using quotes.

I have also given using .NET a try, but doing a .StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() causes it to hang; deadlock maybe? Even though I am placing it well before the exit and I have it sleep a bit before any type of exit takes place:

```
$ps = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
$ps.StartInfo.FileName = "P:\path\plink.exe"
$ps.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh -l user -pw password $addrss"

[void]$ps.Start() 

Start-Sleep -m 500
$ps.StandardInput.Write("cd c:/scot/bin`r")
Start-Sleep -m 500
$ps.StandardInput.Write("GetDiagFiles.exe`r")
Start-Sleep -m 500
$ps.StandardInput.Write("cd c:/temp`r")
Start-Sleep -m 500
$ps.StandardInput.Write("ls *.zip`r")
Start-Sleep -m 500
$ps.StandardInput.Write("cd c:/scot/monitor`r")
$Out = $ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Start-Sleep -s 10
$ps.StandardInput.Write("exit`r")

$PlinkStreamWriter.Close();
if (!$ps.HasExited) { $ps.Kill() }
$Out
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I have scoured over everything at MSDN and nothing.

Comment: Do you connect to a Windows server running Cygwin? Your combination of calling `.exe` file, but using *nix commands (`ls`) is unusual. Does the command sequence work, if you type it manually in SSH terminal (PuTTY)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing what you ask should be as easy as:

```
plink -ssh -l user -pw password -m script.txt > output.log
```

Where the `script.txt` contains your commands:

```
cd c:/scot/bin
GetDiagFiles.exe
cd c:/temp
ls *.zip
cd c:/scot/monitor
exit
```

*If this does not work (as you claim you have tried something similar), give us more details about the problem.*

Comment: This worked just right.  I still have to call it using &, but it seems to output the info right.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created a `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` object to feed into the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object.

You needed to put `` `n `` at the end of the commands not `` `r ``, or you can remove them altogether when using the `.WriteLine` method

I tested the code below using some cmd.exe and made the alterations you need, it should work with plink.exe

```psh
$ProcessStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$ProcessStartInfo.FileName = "P:\path\plink.exe"
$ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh -l user -pw password $addrss"

$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessStartInfo
$Process.Start() | Out-Null

$Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd c:/scot/bin")
$Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("GetDiagFiles.exe")
$Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd c:/temp")
$Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ls *.zip")
$Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd c:/scot/monitor")
$Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit")

$Process.WaitForExit()

$stdoutput = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$erroutput = $Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

Write-Host "Standard Output: $stdoutput"
Write-Host "Error Output : $erroutput"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $Process.ExitCode
```

Comment: The `WriteLine` method already appends a newline to the string. Manually adding one shouldn't be required.